# Pyspark comparison operator

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

When I try to compare two columns in a Data-frame using comparison operator and not able to get the accurate results so can someone guide me where I am doing wrong

```
>>>spark.sql("select High,Low from cc where cc.High < cc.Low").show(5) 
+--------+-------+
|High    |Low    |
+--------+-------+
|      14|      4|
|      19|      3|
|      24|      5|
|      46|      6|
|     106|      8|
+--------+-------+
```

only showing top 5 rows

So the High and Low columns are string datatype.

The value of 14 is greater than value of 4. so the resulted output is wrong so where I am doing wrong???

Comment: It's because they are strings, as you said. You can check to see that `print('14' < '4')` returns `True` (caveat, the comparison is probably happening in the JVM, but it's probably the same outcome as python). If you want the computation done on integer values, you'll need to do a cast: `"select High,Low from cc where CAST(cc.High AS INTEGER) < CAST(cc.Low AS INTEGER)"`

Comment: @pault, you should format that into an answer! :-)

Answer (score 2):

> the High and Low columns are string datatype.

The comparison is happening lexicographically. In python you can see this is the case via some simple test cases:

```
print('14' < '4')
#True

print('44' < '4')
#False
```

In the first case, the comparison is `'1' < '4'`, which return `True`.

In order to do numeric comparisons, you can convert to integers:

```python
spark.sql(
    "select High,Low from cc where CAST(High AS INTEGER) < CAST(Low AS INTEGER)"
).show()
```

---

Notes on lexicographical comparison from some Java [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29):

> This is the definition of lexicographic ordering. If two strings are
>   different, then either they have different characters at some index
>   that is a valid index for both strings, or their lengths are
>   different, or both. If they have different characters at one or more
>   index positions, let k be the smallest such index; then the string
>   whose character at position k has the smaller value, as determined by
>   using the < operator, lexicographically precedes the other string. In
>   this case, `compareTo` returns the difference of the two character
>   values at position k in the two string -- that is, the value:
>
> ```
> this.charAt(k)-anotherString.charAt(k)
> ```
>
> If there is no index position at which they differ, then the shorter string
>   lexicographically precedes the longer string. In this case, compareTo
>   returns the difference of the lengths of the strings -- that is, the
>   value:
>
> ```
> this.length()-anotherString.length()
> ```